# Displaying download speed in Download manager notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-download-manager

Q1. I'm new to android. I'm trying to develop an app which uses download manager. I want to display download speed of the connection (mobile/Wifi whatever connection is the user on and downloading). I don't how to achieve this.

Q2. Is there any issues with the download manager not downloading via local address like 192.168.*.*/file_name.extn? only when data is on then the download notification appears but the download doesn't always fails. The server works fine, works on the browser.

The code im using :

```
        String url  =mainActivity_downloadLink.getText().toString();
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setTitle("Testing ");
        request.setDescription("the file is downloading");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
         , request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,""+System.currentTimeMillis());
        //request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

Any help thanks in advance.

---

Comment: For Q2, what is the error that you see in your logcat?

Comment: for Q2, the download gets into queue but it fails everytime. if i switch off the mobile data then the download manager notification disappears, i dont know why. Nothing much is shown in the logcat.